# IndexError: no such group - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rename

Can anyone help with answering why I'm getting the following error?

###### Error :

```
File "./digiimport-s5.py", line 77, in processdir
    finddate = (finddate[0:24] + ".jpeg")
IndexError: no such group
```

###### Code Snippet :

```
if f.startswith("signal"):
    finddate = re.match("signal-(\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+).jpeg",f)
    if finddate:
        finddate = (finddate[0:24] + ".jpeg")
        desttime = datetime.strptime(finddate.groups()[0], "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S")
    else:
        print(f"{f} has not the right convention ", end='')`
```

I'm trying to strip out the "-8" out of a signal picture name `signal-2022-04-08-124608-8.jpeg` so that it can be parsed by `strptime`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code and question properly, take a look at [*How do I format my code blocks?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/1289775) if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

After running your code and taking a look at the stack trace, the faulty part seems to be `finddate[0:24]`, which attempts to access 24 capture groups from the match object, which is failing because the object only contains 2 groups.

Presumably you wanted to grab 24 characters from the original string (i.e. do `f[:24]`) rather than groups from the match object `finddate`.

```py
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-90d301324e49> in <module>
      2     finddate = re.match("signal-(\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+).jpeg",f)
      3     if finddate:
----> 4         finddate = (finddate[0:24] + ".jpeg")
      5         desttime = datetime.strptime(finddate.groups()[0], "%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S")
      6     else:

IndexError: no such group
```